# write jQuery.parseJSON in if condition

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm doing an ajax request with query and wondering how to write jQuery.parseJSON in if condition.my

`echo json_encode($result) is {"flag":"1"}` in ajax i want to check if flag = 1 i want to redirect,it showing an error

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after condition
                  if(obj == "flag":"1"){
```

see my ajax code can anyone guide me how to do that.thanks

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#redirect").click(function() {

        data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

         var obj = data;

         alert(JSON.stringify(obj));

        if(obj == "flag":"1"){

             $.blockUI(

       { 

         message: '<h2>Please wait...</h2><img src="/image/loader.gif" />',
     timeout: 2000

       });
       $.ajax({
            type:"post",

        data:"clientid="+clientid,
        success:function(data){

                         window.location = '?action=clientroutingchange&clientid='+clientid+'';
                          $("#result").html(data);
                         $('.blockUI').hide();
        }


    });


        }
        else{

            alert("no changes in route")
        }

          });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `if(obj.flag == "1")` after parse JSON. Avoid if(obj == "flag":"1")

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#redirect").click(function() {

            data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

             var obj = data;

            // alert(JSON.stringify(obj));

            if(obj.flag == "1"){

                 $.blockUI(

           { 

             message: '<h2>Please wait...</h2><img src="/image/loader.gif" />',
         timeout: 2000

           });
           $.ajax({
                type:"post",

            data:"clientid="+clientid,
            success:function(data){

                             window.location = '?action=clientroutingchange&clientid='+clientid+'';
                              $("#result").html(data);
                             $('.blockUI').hide();
            }


        });


            }
            else{

                alert("no changes in route")
            }

              });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax should be

```
if(obj.flag == "1"){
```

OR if you prefer you can do

```
if(obj['flag'] == "1"){
```